# Por qué no puedo usar Scanner.nextInt() para leer una contraseña con al menos una letra

Tags: java

tengo un problema con mi código solo se ejecuta hasta cierto punto, cuando esta así:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre = "";
    String apellido = "";
    int contraseña = 0;
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu nombre? (comienza con mayúscula)");
    nombre = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu apellido? (comienza con mayúscula)");
    apellido = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Crea tu contraseña (que contenga al menos una letra)");
    contraseña = in.nextInt();
```

Funciona bien si solo dejo escrito así el código, pero si le agrego al final esto:

```
System.out.println("tu nombre es" + nombre +",tu apellido es"+ apellido +"y tu contraseña es" + contraseña);
```

No se ejecuta nada del código y me aparece este mensaje: ***"Los resultados de compilación están desactualizados para el alcance de compilación solicitado.
La compilación incremental subsiguiente compilará archivos para las fuentes modificadas y eliminará los resultados obsoletos de la compilación anterior."***

No entiendo porqué dice eso, por cierto utilizo [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) edicion 2022.1.3.

Comment: tu contraseña como indicas debe ser un conjunto de números y letras ,por ende la variable contraseña debe ser de tipo String de lo contrario te lanzara una excepción

Comment: Dramaturgo muchas gracias ya me funciona el código! :D

Comment: En teoría ese mensaje no es importante. Solo te dice que en lugar de compilar todo el proyecto, compilará los archivos que tengan modificaciones.

Comment: Genial,Hola y bienvenid@ te invito a realizar el respectivo [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour),saludos

Comment: Mateo, ah ya entiendo, gracias :D

Comment: Ok iré por ese recorrido